# Python consumes excessive memory, doesn't complete run even given adequate memory

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I am writing a code for an information retrieval project, which reads Wikipedia pages in XML format from a file, processes the string (I've omitted this part for the sake of simplicity), tokenizes the strings and build positional indexes for the terms found on the pages. Then it saves the indexes to a file using pickle once, and then reads it from that file for the next usages for less processing time (I've included the code for that parts, but they're commented)

After that, I need to fill a 1572 * ~97000 matrix (1572 is the number of Wiki pages, and 97000 is the number of terms found in them. Like each Wiki page is a vector of words, and `vectors[i][j]` is, the number of occurrences of the i'th word of the word set in the j'th Wiki Page. (Again it's been simplified but it doesn't matter)

The problem is that it takes way too much memory to run the code, and even then, from a point between the 350th and 400th row of the matrix beyond, it doesn't proceed to run the code (it doesn't stop either). I thought the problem was with memory, because when its usage exceeded my 7.7GiB RAM and 1.7GiB swap, it stopped and printed:

> Process finished with exit code 137 (interrupted by signal 9: SIGKILL)

But when I added a 6GiB memory by making a swap file for Python3.7 (using the script recommended [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/799836), the program didn't run out of memory, but instead got stuck when it had 7.7GiB RAM + 3.9GiB swap memory occupied) as I said, at a point between the 350th and 400th iteration of `i` in the loop at the bottom. Instead of Ubuntu 18.04,I tried it on Windows 10, the screen simply went black. I tried this on Windows 7, again to no avail.

Next I thought it was a PyCharm issue, so I ran the python file using the `python3 file.py` command, and it got stuck at the very point it had with PyCharm. I even used the `numpy.float16` datatype to save memory, but it had no effect. I asked a colleague about their matrix dimensions, they were similar to mine, but they weren't having problems with it. Is it malware or a memory leak? Or is it something am I doing something wrong here?

```
import pickle
from hazm import *
from collections import defaultdict
import numpy as np

'''For each word there's one of these. it stores the word's frequency, and the positions it has occurred in on each wiki page'''


class Positional_Index:
    def __init__(self):
        self.freq = 0
        self.title = defaultdict(list)
        self.text = defaultdict(list)

'''Here I tokenize words and construct indexes for them'''

# tree = ET.parse('Wiki.xml')
# root = tree.getroot()
# index_dict = defaultdict(Positional_Index)
# all_content = root.findall('{http://www.mediawiki.org/xml/export-0.10/}page')
# 
# for page_index, pg in enumerate(all_content):
#     title = pg.find('{http://www.mediawiki.org/xml/export-0.10/}title').text
#     txt = pg.find('{http://www.mediawiki.org/xml/export-0.10/}revision') \
#         .find('{http://www.mediawiki.org/xml/export-0.10/}text').text
# 
#     title_arr = word_tokenize(title)
#     txt_arr = word_tokenize(txt)
# 
#     for term_index, term in enumerate(title_arr):
#         index_dict[term].freq += 1
#         index_dict[term].title[page_index] += [term_index]
# 
#     for term_index, term in enumerate(txt_arr):
#         index_dict[term].freq += 1
#         index_dict[term].text[page_index] += [term_index]
# 
# with open('texts/indices.txt', 'wb') as f:
#     pickle.dump(index_dict, f)


with open('texts/indices.txt', 'rb') as file:
    data = pickle.load(file)

'''Here I'm trying to keep the number of occurrences of each word on each page'''
page_count = 1572
vectors = np.array([[0 for j in range(len(data.keys()))] for i in range(page_count)], dtype=np.float16)
words = list(data.keys())
word_count = len(words)

const_log_of_d = np.log10(1572)

""" :( """
for i in range(page_count):
    for j in range(word_count):
        vectors[i][j] = (len(data[words[j]].title[i]) + len(data[words[j]].text[i]))
    if i % 50 == 0:
        print("i:", i)
```

Update : I tried this on a friend's computer, this time it killed the process at someplace between the 1350th-1400th iteration.

Comment: 1572 * 97000 * 2 bytes (for float16) is just 300 megabytes. There's something else at play here. Hmm - would `vectors[i, j]` work better?

Comment: @AKX I tried it. Didn't change the result. But something's wrong with python. I stopped the process in PyCharm, it still appeared in my system monitor. 6.7 GiB memory and 6.8 GiB disk read total.